# Electric moment from the Pauli term?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, magnetic-moment

The Pauli term is roughly given by
$$M_{\mu\nu}F^{\mu\nu} = K\cdot E + J\cdot B$$ where $K$ is the boost and $E$ is the electric field and $J$ is the angular momentum and $B$ is the magnetic field. We know the second term to be the magnetic moment of the particle but what about the first term? Is it the ''electric moment"? Does it have any physical meaning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed the relativistic generalization of the Pauli interaction ${\vec \sigma} \cdot {\vec B}$ is $$\frac{i}{2} [\sigma_\mu, \sigma_\nu] ~F^{\mu\nu}\,.$$

The electrical part is a.o. responsible for the spin-orbit interaction. For more insight check out the treatment of the relativistic hydrogen atom in Itzykson &Zuber, Quantum Field Theory.